# myloader Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: mysql, bug-reporting, segmentation-fault

```
myloader --directory=$DB_DUMP --queries-per-transaction=50000 \
         --threads=$THREADS --compress-protocol --verbose=3 \
         --socket=$MYSQL_SOCK --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS

# ldd /usr/bin/myloader
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa8e48000)
    libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007f44b87e1000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f44b85c4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f44b83ac000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f44b80b0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f44b7ce8000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f44b7a8a000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f44b76af000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f44b74ab000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f44b72a2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f44b6f9d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f44b8cfa000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f44b6d5e000)

# myloader -V
myloader 0.5.1, built against MySQL 5.5.27

# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1


# sh -x ./mydumper_recovery.sh
+ DB_DUMP=/root/bck/MYSQL/last_dump
+ THREADS=2
+ MYSQL_USER=root
+ MYSQL_PASS=
+ MYSQL_SOCK=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
+ myloader --directory=/root/bck/MYSQL/last_dump --queries-per-transaction=50000 --threads=2 --compress-protocol --verbose=3 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --user=root --password=
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

# cat /etc/issue.net
Ubuntu 13.04
```

Comment: New version not listern on official repository 0.5.2 https://launchpad.net/mydumper

Comment: Do you see a file named core created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should report this as a bug in the bug reporter for the project: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: done `ubuntu-bug /var/crash/_usr_bin_myloader.0.crash`